# Hash and Skiplists index in parallel?

Tags: indexing, arangodb

Does it make sense to have a hash index and a skiplists index **in parallel** for the **same** field? Will Arango use the hash index for equality queries and the skiplists index for range requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to have a skiplist index and a hash index on the same attribute (or even multiple attributes).
Which index is used for a query depends on several factors:

- for equality lookups: the selectivity estimate of the index (if provided by the index type)
- for range queries: the number of bounds used (a filter condition such as `attribute > leftBound && attribute < rightBound` will have a higher chance to use the skiplist index than just `attribute > leftBound`)
- the number of documents in the collection
- if the index can be used to optimize away a later SORT clause
- if the index is sparse: if the condition can include the `null` value (in this case the index will not be used, regardless of whether it is a hash or skiplist index)

Which index is going to be used (if any at all) will always be revealed by running `db._explain(query)` on a specific query.

Having multiple indexes on the same attributes however has the drawback that each individual index will slow down writes to the collection a bit. For RocksDB-based indexes, each additional index will also consume disk space. For MMFiles-based indexes, the index buildup time on server start/collection load is a factor to take into account and the additional RAM usage of each index.

So in most cases it is a tradeoff between the extra lookup speed you may gain for some queries vs. the costs of extra memory/disk space and index buildup/maintenance.